# Можно ли выполнить данную строку без подключения jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Можно ли выполнить данную строку без подключения jQuery?

```
${this.data}${text};

const obj = { data: '123' };
const append = function (text) {
    return ${this.data}${text};
};
obj.append = append;
console.log(obj.append('45'));
```

Comment: А посмотреть самому религия не позволяет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А при чём тут jQuery?

Тут больше похоже просто на ошибку — забытые кавычки. Наверное так:

```
return `${this.data}${text}`;
```

https://doka.guide/js/template-strings/
https://learn.javascript.ru/string